# Using QOpenGLDebugLogger on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opengl

I would like to be able to use the *QOpenGLDebugLogger* feature on MacOS.

I understood that I had to create a specific *QOpenGLContext* so here is my code in my custom *QOpenGLWidget* class constructor:

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setMajorVersion(3);
format.setMinorVersion(2);
format.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

Unfortunately, it has no effect on the current context created by my *QOpenGLWidget*. The following code in my *initializeGL()* overriden method outputs false:

```
qDebug() << QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->hasExtension(QByteArrayLiteral("GL_KHR_debug"));
```

I noticed that the *QOpenGLContext* version seems always to be *2.1*:

```
qDebug() << QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->format().majorVersion() << QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->format().minorVersion();
```

Any idea why settings the format in the constructor has no effect?

Comment: In fact I'm first trying to make it works with MacOS desktop OpenGL without success

Comment: I just made the edit!

Comment: Have you tried calling `setFormat` of your `QOpenGLWidget` instead of `QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat` as described [here (3rd code block)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#details)

Comment: I should also mention, that `KHR_debug` was added to core in 4.3, so it might not be supported by a 3.2 context. (And it might also not be possible to create a 3.2 debug context).

Comment: Using `QOpenGLWidget::setFormat()` change something: I now have a 4.1 opengl context. Unfortunately the `GL_KHR_debug` extension is still unsupported...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to request a specific OpenGL context version from the constructor of a `QOpenGLWidget` is to call the `QOpenGLWidget::setFormat(..)` method. Also note, that KHR_DEBUG was introduced in OpenGL 4.3 Core Profile, so it might be impossible to use this functionality before that. The correct setup code for a OpenGL 4.3 Debug context would be

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setMajorVersion(4);
format.setMinorVersion(3);
format.setOption(QSurfaceFormat::DebugContext);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
setFormat(format);
```

Comment: Does your hardware support 4.3?

Comment: How can I know that?

Comment: Which graphics card do you have?

Comment: Intel Iris 1536 Mo

Comment: According to this page, my macbook support only OpenGL 4.1: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823

Comment: So then you have your answer: If the hardware only supports 4.1 then there is no way to get anything newer.